# How to restrict no of suggestions a user can select to 2 in jquery autocomplete?

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I am using jquery autocomplete in on of my application.

What i want is that the no of suggestions a user can select should be restricted to 2?

I have following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#txtTopic').autocomplete('include/ajax.php?option=searchtopics', {
            minChars: 2,
            max:10, /* maximum number of records to display at one time */
            autoFill: true,
            multiple: true
                });

            })

    </script>
```

Right now since multiple is true a user is able to select more than 2 suggestions.

He should be able to select only 2 suggestions.

Comment: What plugin are you using exactly ? The options is your example are not supported by the official `jQuery Autocomplete` from `jQuery UI` http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: pomesh thanks for replying. i am using http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/

Comment: "Note (2010-06-23): This plugin is deprecated and not developed anymore." If you can, you should definitely switch to the official plugin :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the select event for checking the limit

```
$('#txtTopic').autocomplete('include/ajax.php?option=searchtopics', {
    minChars: 2,
    max:10, /* maximum number of records to display at one time */
    autoFill: true,
    multiple: true,
    select: function(event, ui) {
    var terms = split(this.value);

    if (terms.length <= 2) {
        // add the selected item
        terms.pop();
        terms.push(ui.item.value);
        terms.push("");            
    } else {
        terms.pop();
    }            

      this.value = terms.join(", ");
       return false;     
    }
  }
});
```

Edit: The above code snippet is for jQuery UI Autocomplete. [LiveDemo](http://jsfiddle.net/mprabhat/qkLu5/1/)

Comment: thanks mprabhat for replying i have made the suggested changes but still its not working

Comment: this code snippet assumes that you are using jQuery UI Autocomplete